# Show more/less in search result with JavaScript and XSLT

Tags: sharepoint-designer, search-results, xslt

I have a metadata with the name **"productiondescription"**, in my advanced search, I want to display this **"productiondescription"** in the search results. And I had changed **srch-Description2** in the code XSLT (I modified in the web part Search result)

The productiondescription shows the first 3 lines in the search results (works well), but the more/less does not work. If I click on **More>>**, nothing appears. And the rest productiondescription cannot display.

I am sure that my JavaScript code is not right. I had tried other methodes, but nothing works. Here is my code

```
<div class="srch-Description2">

<xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="string-length($productiondescription) &lt; 400">
  <div id="itemdescription">
          <xsl:value-of select="$productiondescription" />
      </div> 
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>
      <div id="itemdescriptionless">
          <xsl:value-of select="substring($productiondescription,1,400)" />
      </div>
        <a href="#" onclick="javascript:moreless(this,'{productiondescription}')">more&gt;&gt;</a>
      </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function moreless(abc,fullText)
      {
      if(abc.innerText == "more&gt;&gt;")
      {
      div = abc.parentNode.getElementsByTagName('div');
      div[0].innerText = fullText;
      abc.innerText = "&lt;&lt;less";
      }
      else if(abc.innerText == "&lt;&lt;less")
      {
      div = abc.parentNode.getElementsByTagName('div');
      div[0].innerText = fullText.substring(0,400);
      abc.innerText = "more&gt;&gt;";
      }
    </script>   
</div >
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer:

First, **javascript:moreless(this,'{productiondescription}')** does not work, I delete '{productiondescription}'

Second, I delete **fullText** in function moreless(abc,fullText)

Third, I add full description and short description to XSLT, and then I add the following code to JS and hide full description. I know it is not a good idea but I cannot find another one

```
 var fulldescriptions = document.getElementById("fullproductiondescription").innerHTML;
```

Fourth, I change **abc.innerText** to abc.innerHTML, and it works well !!!